# Error running migrations in a docker container

Tags: python, docker-compose, dockerfile, alembic

I am getting this error when trying to run migrations in my container. I cannot seem to figure out why.

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"alembic\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.2
WORKDIR /workspace/
COPY . .
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --deploy --ignore-pipfile
#EXPOSE 8000
#CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "/workspace/bin/web.py"]
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env.database.local
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/workspace
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    command: "alembic upgrade head && pipenv run python /workspace/bin/web.py"
```

The command I run when I encounter this problem:

```
docker-compose run web alembic revision - autogenerate -m "First migration"
```

[image: Project Directory.]

I defined in my Dockerfile that all my program will be running in the workspace directory. So it  should point to it.

Comment: Looks like `alembic` isn't in your container `PATH`. Does your docker image have `alembic` included? You may have to manually install it in the `Dockerfile` if not.

Comment: It should already be installed because of pipenv. Which is what I am confused about.

Comment: Hm. Where is `pipenv` installing it to? `alembic` could be installed but your container doesn't know where to find it because the shell `PATH` variable doesn't include the path to the `alembic` executable.

Comment: alembic is a binary thats sitting inside the venv pipenv creates. @jonsbox, answer is correct but missing the context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue was that I did not add it to my $PATH.

This is what I added inside my docker-compose:

```
      - PATH=/directory/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Where in your docker-compose did you write it?

Comment: I changed my compose file since the initial question but it would be in the `environment:`. As an example you look for the `web` service in my question.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose run web pipenv run alembic revision - autogenerate -m "First migration"`

or
change in Dockerfile

`RUN pipenv install --deploy --ignore-pipfile --system`

and run

`docker-compose run web alembic revision - autogenerate -m "First migration"`